# trigger for checking occurrences of a value

Tags: oracle, triggers

There is a MODEL table as follow

```
create table MODEL (
model_name VARCHAR(20),
model_year NUMBER,
consumption VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
Component component_ty_nt,
Distributor distributor_ty_nt,
Car car_ty_nt,
constraint t_pk primary key (Model_Name, Model_Year))
nested table Component store as component_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Distributor store as distributor_ty_nt_TAB
nested table Car store as car_ty_nt_TAB
```

the Component_ty

```
Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
Code VARCHAR(10),
Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
Component_Type VARCHAR(10))
NOT FINAL;
```

has component_type attribute which can be 'body', 'engine' or 'equipment'

Every time I perform an INSERT on this table I need a trigger that checks the occurrences of the types and return an error if the occurrences of Boyd != 1 or the occurrences of 'Engine' != 1
I've tried with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_engine_and_body
BEFORE INSERT ON model
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
engineCounter NUMBER;
bodyCounter NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..:new.Component.COUNT LOOP
    IF deref(:new.Component(i)).Component_Type = 'Engine' THEN
      engineCounter := engineCounter + 1;
    ELSIF deref(:new.Component(i)).Component_Type = 'Body' THEN
      bodyCounter := bodyCounter + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF engineCounter != 1 OR bodyCounter != 1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Incorrect occurrences for component_type attribute');
  END IF;
END;
```

but I get error:

```
PL/SQL: Statement ignore 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DEREF'
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to work out why your trigger fails but checking using SQL (rather than PL/SQL works).

---

I am assuming that you have the types and table:

```sql
Create or replace type Component_ty as object (
Code VARCHAR(10),
Component_Description VARCHAR(100),
Component_Type VARCHAR(10))
NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE component_ty_nt AS TABLE OF REF component_ty;

CREATE TABLE components OF component_ty;

create table MODEL (
  model_name VARCHAR(20),
  model_year NUMBER,
  Component component_ty_nt,
  constraint t_pk primary key (Model_Name, Model_Year)
)
nested table Component store as component_ty_nt_TAB;

ALTER TABLE component_ty_nt_TAB ADD SCOPE FOR (COLUMN_VALUE) IS components;
```

Then you can use the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_engine_and_body
  BEFORE INSERT ON model
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  counter PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   counter
  FROM   TABLE(:NEW.Component) c
  WHERE  DEREF(c.COLUMN_VALUE).component_type IN ('Engine', 'Body')
  HAVING COUNT(CASE DEREF(c.COLUMN_VALUE).component_type WHEN 'Engine' THEN 1 END) = 1
  AND    COUNT(CASE DEREF(c.COLUMN_VALUE).component_type WHEN 'Body'   THEN 1 END) = 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Incorrect occurrences for component_type attribute');
END;
/
```

Which for the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO components 
  SELECT component_ty('A', 'AAA', 'Engine') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT component_ty('B', 'BBB', 'Body')   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT component_ty('C', 'CCC', 'Other')  FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('A', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B')
));

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('E', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C')
));
```

works and:

```
INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('B', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A')
));

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('C', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B')
));

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('D', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C')
));

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('F', 1, component_ty_nt());

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('G', 1, NULL);

INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('H', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C')
));
```

Each fail with the error:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Incorrect occurrences for component_type attribute
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_FGDYNUZQHDRDVPAYKGUH.CHECK_ENGINE_AND_BODY", line 12
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_FGDYNUZQHDRDVPAYKGUH.CHECK_ENGINE_AND_BODY'
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XzzYvLpb)

Comment: Thank you! 
``` 
INSERT INTO model (model_name, model_year, component)
VALUES ('E', 1, component_ty_nt(
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C'),
 (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'A'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'B'),
  (SELECT REF(c) FROM components c WHERE code = 'C')
));
``` 
it insert a new row, and it shouldn't

Comment: @mikerug88 change `> 0` to `= 1`.

Comment: yeah I tried it already, but still it let me insert a row with 2 types engine and 2 types body

Comment: I think the problem is in the exception, it is raised only when no data is found, but not when more thank 1 data is found

Comment: @mikerug88 It works fine in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o7WnMk4m) and you can see from the query at the end of the fiddle that it produces no rows when there are multiple bodies or engines. It will only produce a row when there is exactly one body and exactly one engine; any other time it will generate no rows and trigger the exception.

Comment: ok, the problem was in the way I was inserting components in model. I was using      cast(multiset(select  ref(c) from component c where code in('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'))

Comment: @mikerug88 The problem is that `IN` will not generate duplicates. `CAST(MULTISET(...) AS component_ty_nt)` works and will raise the error if you can generate duplicates [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pLoWOQUm)